# Text Mining on Twitter

Tags: r, tm

I am trying to follow tutorial [1](http://www.r-bloggers.com/r-text-mining-on-twitter-prayformh370-malaysia-airlines/) to do text mining on twitter
My codes are:

```
library(twitteR)
library(NLP)
library(tm)
library(wordcloud)
library(RColorBrewer)

mh370 <- searchTwitter("#PrayForMH370", since = "2014-03-08", until =     "2014-03-20", n = 1000)
mh370_text = sapply(mh370, function(x) x$getText())
mh370_corpus = Corpus(VectorSource(mh370_text))

tdm = TermDocumentMatrix(mh370_corpus,control = list(removePunctuation =     TRUE,stopwords = c("prayformh370", "prayformh",    stopwords("english")),removeNumbers = TRUE, tolower = TRUE))
m = as.matrix(tdm)
# get word counts in decreasing order
word_freqs = sort(rowSums(m), decreasing = TRUE) 
# create a data frame with words and their frequencies
dm = data.frame(word = names(word_freqs), freq = word_freqs)
wordcloud(dm$word,dm$freq,random.order=FALSE,colors=brewer.pal(8,"Dark2"))
```

When I run the last code, I get this error:

```
Error in strwidth(words[i], cex = size[i], ...) : invalid 'cex' value
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In max(freq) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
2: In max(freq) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

Please advice.

Comment: Check the max and min frequencies in the data frame dm, and also try creating the wordcloud with lesser number of words first. Remove whitespaces and try.

Answer (score 0):

As [Vikram](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5078728/vikram-venkat) said, maybe you should reduce the number of words in your plot by adding `max.words` to your wordcloud.

```
wordcloud(dm$word, dm$freq, scale=c(8,3), min.freq=2, max.words=120,
          random.order=FALSE, colors=brewer.pal(8,"Dark2"))
```

I also suggest using `min.freq` to plot words that appear at least twice and `scale` to control the size of the words. Adjust those until you get a nice plot.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to `removeSparseTerms` as well. I encountered a similar problem, and I found this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20343941/wordcloud-package-get-error-in-strwidth-invalid-cex-value) some time ago. I had to modify the solution though, but removing sparse terms worked. `tm` package has the function.