# Power BI WordCloud with R value 'cex' incorrect

Tags: r, date, powerbi, word-cloud

I'm trying to print a date on PowerBI, as a result of a function. I'm trying to achive that using wordcloud to print the result date. This question has already been asked, but what I find curious is that this error doesn't happen on RStudio but it does on Power BI R.

[wordcloud package: get “Error in strwidth(…) : invalid 'cex' value”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20343941/wordcloud-package-get-error-in-strwidth-invalid-cex-value)

http://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Issue-WordCloud-with-R/td-p/202004

```
mydate <- as.character(factor("1/15/2006"))
var <- as.Date(mydate, format = "%m/%d/%y")
library("wordcloud")
wordcloud(words = c( var ), freq = c(10) , scale=c(1,.5),colors=c('red'))
```

that code on RStudios works fine, but on PowerBI it saids :

> Error in strwidth(words[i], cex = size[i], ... : value 'cex' incorrect
>   Calls: wordcloud -> strwidth

Please help me achive printing a date on Power BI. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question was wrongly asked but the answer to my problem was :

var<-  paste( dataset$Day , dataset$Month,  dataset$Year , sep='-'  )

power Bi takes the date, and split it. So I got to put it together .