# Error in strwidth(words[i], cex = size[i], ...) : invalid 'cex' value

Tags: r, tm, word-cloud

I am using the tm and wordcloud packages. I am trying to make a word cloud from a DTM. Here is the code:

```
ocs <- Corpus(VectorSource(text))
trans <- content_transformer(function(x, pattern) gsub(pattern," ",x))
Docs <- tm_map(Docs, trans, "/")
Docs <- tm_map(Docs, trans, "@")
Docs <- tm_map(Docs, trans, "//|")
Docs <- tm_map(Docs, content_transformer(tolower))
Docs <- tm_map(Docs, removeNumbers)
Docs <- tm_map(Docs, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
Docs <- tm_map(Docs, removePunctuation)
Docs <- tm_map(Docs, stripWhitespace)
Docs <- tm_map(Docs, stemDocument)
Docs <- tm_map(Docs, wordLength)
dtm <- TermDocumentMatrix(Docs)
mat <- as.matrix(dtm)
v <- sort(rowSums(mat), decreasing = TRUE)
Data <- data.frame(word = names(v), freq = v)
set.seed(1056)
wordcloud(words = Data$word, freq = Data$freq, min.freq = 1,
      max.words = 200, random.order = FALSE, rot.per = 0.35,
      colors = brewer.pal(8,"Dark2"))
```

Error found : Error in strwidth(words[i], cex = size[i], ...) : invalid 'cex' value. Can somebody tell me a fix for the error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [wordcloud package: get “Error in strwidth(…) : invalid 'cex' value”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20343941/wordcloud-package-get-error-in-strwidth-invalid-cex-value)